# Excel Formula: Subtracting Total values if Price, Qty, and Part are equal to Price, Qty, and Part Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

This is my first post. Please see the attached Photo. The items highlighted in yellow is the criteria I'm trying to create.

I want to subtract the Extended Values (G-L) if the Buy is not optimal and the Price and Qty in cells columns D and F exist in the range of cells in columns J and K and the value in Column B = the value in Column R.

Below is the formula that works for some of the cases, but not all.

```
=IFNA(IF(AND(H7="Optimal Buy",P7="",IFNA(MATCH(D7,X:X,0),0)>0,IFNA(MATCH(F7,W:W,0),0)>0),G7-L7,""),"")
```

Formula Question:
[image: Formula Question]